# How to test a rdfa parser?

Tags: node.js, rdf, microdata, rdfa

I'm trying to find a way to check if my rdfa-parser (written in nodejs) is working.
So I have an rdfa-parser, which should print all triples, found in a file or url (with rdfa-syntax).

So far I know, that there are testsuits for RDFa-parsing (http://rdfa.info/test-suite/rdfa1.1/html5/manifest), but I'm not sure how to use them.

Is there a good webpage, where this is described? Or can anyone help me in another way?

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is off-topic here. Can you be more specific where your problem is exactly? How did you try to use these tests? Please [edit] your question to describe it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be some information at the rdfa.info/tests site. Basically, you need a service that will accept a GET request, where the "uri" query parameter points to the input file. The service then parses the file, and returns some other form of RDF, typically N-Triples. More information on the Github page: https://github.com/rdfa/rdfa-website/blob/master/README.md